# Multiple Part Questions

Tags: discussion

1. I see a lot of questions that are kind of interviewing questions with multiple parts. The answers get daunting when it gets beyond 2 parts.
2. What should we do with these questions? Answer them in parts? Ask the OP to split the post up?
3. Support your response. Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My rule of thumb:

**I will tolerate a question with two parts as long as the parts are reasonably related.**

A question with more than two parts, or where the (n) questions it asks are wildly different and/or unrelated, I will vote to close as "Not a Real Question" and leave a comment indicating the question should be narrowed or broken apart into sub-questions.

Answer (score 5):

I think that it's best to ask separate questions and post links in their body. This way, one correct answer can be accepted for each question.

Furthermore form what I've seen, in questions with multiple subquestion, people tend to post answer which do not answer all subquestions. This way, it can happen that some point go unanswered. IF each point is separate question, I believe that people will pay more attention to each individual point.